# Designing a "Verified" user status

Tags: asp.net, user-experience

I am working on a project where I need to design the logic for a `Verified` user. This means that a user (based on negative feedback) is not able to delete their account and start a new account under a different email id.

Currently, to create an account, a user enters :

```
desired userID,  
email address (yahoo, gmail etc),  
Address,  
City,  
State,  
Zip,  
Phone
```

How can I ensure if a user does close their account and start a new account, that the application can track this?

One option suggested was to send a secure code to the user's cell phone;

Answer (score 3):

Unless they use the same details you can't. The only thing you can reliably compare is the e-mail address and everyone has several of these already and it's easy to get more.

You will have to be careful if you only allow one sign up per address as this will prevent members of the same family signing up to your service.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reliable way of doing this, unfortunatelly. Unless, of course, you'd ask user for an SSN number and then validate it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the combination of data you collect is open ended and their are virtually infinite possibilities for each value, I'm not sure you can prevent this, unless each user is tied to another device, such as a hardware key token or some other non user provided hardware based out of band authentication.